# Two loops with same variable but different range

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to make a program that prints *n* sections and *x_1, x_2,..., x_n* subsections for each section in LaTeX. With this I mean that I named a variable numsec, which asks me how many sections I want, easy enough. Then after, a variable numsubsec asks me how many subsections I want. Now the answer to that input ought to be like this: say I want 3 sections, my answer to the subsection has to be a 3 digit number, so that the first digit determines how many subsections should be in the first section and so on. As an example numsec could be 3, and numsubsec could be 101. That means 1 subsec in the 1st sec, 0 subsec in 2nd sec, 1 subsec in 3rd sec. However, I don't know how to make Python print that, exact answer. Here is my code:

```
def sections(numsec, numsubsec):
    for n, i in range(1, numsec+1), range(0,len(numsubsec)):
        print("")
        print("\section{Opgave "+str(n)+"}")
        print("")
        print("\subsection{}" * int(numsubsec[i]))



def runprogram():
    numsec = int(input("How many sections? "))
    numsubsec = input("How many subsections? ")
    sections(numsec,numsubsec)

runprogram()
```

**EDIT:**
I solved the issue by using to for loops simultaneously with two variables as such:

```
def sections(numsec, numsubsec):
    numbers = []
    numbers.extend(numsubsec) #Splitting the string numsubsec in to a list of its digits
    print("")
    print("Preamble")
    print("")
    for n,i in zip(range(1, numsec+1),range(0,numsec)): #zip the ranges
        print("")
        print("\section{Opgave "+str(n)+"}")
        print("")
        for x in range(int(numsubsec[i])):
            print("\subsection{}")
            print("")
```

Comment: two* :) - not 'to'.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, please post your solution as an answer and accept it. Self-answering questions is **encouraged** here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by using two for loops simultaneously, and zipping the ranges as such:

```
def sections(numsec, numsubsec):
    numbers = []
    numbers.extend(numsubsec) #Splitting the string numsubsec in to a list of its digits
    print("")
    print("Preamble")
    print("")
    for n,i in zip(range(1, numsec+1),range(0,numsec)): #zip the ranges
        print("")
        print("\section{Opgave "+str(n)+"}")
        print("")
        for x in range(int(numsubsec[i])):
            print("\subsection{}")
            print("")
```